# How to set React port for development environment with ASP.Net Core 3.0?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.net Core + React application which is created by using template in Visual Studio.

I'm trying to serve react application on a constant port for Windows environment to set cors settings but I couldn't achieved it.

I have tried the approaches listed below, but the result didn't change.

- I have created .env file which contains a line like that. 'PORT:5000'
- I changed the npm command to "start": "set PORT=5000 && react-scripts start "

I have configured the application like that.

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
         spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
     }
 });
```

By the way, for the future versions of Asp.net core they have added DevServerPort parameter in SpaOptions within [commit](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/commit/968e85a3977d3634602891eecd90e456131ae0c3#diff-3de9fe3304f55fc57db25df3ed1dc00c) but for now I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it on `Properties > launchSettings.json`.

Changes needs to be made in this section in `applicationUrl`:

```
"WebApplication1": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000", // CHANGE IT THIS ONE
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Comment: It's already set as you said. But it is still not working.
"App": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

The previous response does not answer the question.  The UseReactDevelopmentServer starts NodeJs on a dynamic port. You can set you UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer to set the location of the server and port. As you previously mentioned, use put the 'set Port=5000' in the 'npm start' command.  The combination of these two changes should addres your needs.